# Postgresql JSON column check key exists

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have wrote query like this to check json column has key

```
SELECT *
FROM "details" 
where ("data"->'country'->'state'->>'city') is not null;
```

How can we write query which will select row if "data" contains "city"

JSON structure of data is not consistent.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can check the **top-level** keys of `data` with `?` as it is said in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html).

For example

```
SELECT * FROM details
WHERE data ? 'city';
```

Checking every key in all nested objects from the json column requires a recursive [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html)

```
select * from details
where 'city' in (
    WITH RECURSIVE t(k,j) as (
        select jsonb_object_keys(details.data), details.data
    UNION ALL
        select jsonb_object_keys(t.j->t.k), t.j->t.k
        FROM t WHERE jsonb_typeof(t.j->t.k) = 'object'
    )
    select k from t
);
```

This of course is not very efficient.

Comment: This works on a JSONB column. The question is about a JSON column, so you have to do a type cast:
`SELECT * FROM details WHERE data::JSONB ? 'city';`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?`:

```
SELECT *
FROM "details" 
WHERE data->'country'->'state' ? 'city';
```

Answer (score -3):

You can convert your json to text and search for the key with LIKE

```
SELECT *
FROM "details"
WHERE "data"::text LIKE '%"city":%'
```

Comment: some json value may contain 'city' text. How you distinguish is this key name or just text?

Comment: well this works for my case where value is a list like this `["abc", "edf"]`

Comment: This query will have a performance degradation as compared to accepted answer.